# Is there a significant difference between making a [IsOneWay=true] WCF service async and calling the sync method using a Task on the client?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

If I have a service defined so:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    [ReceiveContextEnabled(ManualControl = true)]
    void DoSomething(Message<XElement> message);
}
```

and I want to call it asyncronously from my client (using shared contracts not generating from svcutil or add service reference) I can do:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myService.DoSomething(message));

... some other code

task.Wait();
```

I could also define my service to be async:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface ICacheKeyExchangeAsync
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true)]
    [ReceiveContextEnabled(ManualControl = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething(Message<XElement> message, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndDoSomething(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

and do this instead

```
IAsyncResult result = myService.BeginDoSomething(message, null, null);

.... some other code

myService.EndDoSomething(result);
```

Are there significant differences between the approaches?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are a differences in [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) threads utilization.

CLR thread pool splitts threads on two types: worker and I/O (more information about them you can find in [Simple description of worker and I/O threads in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099947/simple-description-of-worker-and-i-o-threads-in-net) and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Generally speaking, thread pool gives you 250 worker threads per core and 1000 I/O threads, so you can use worker threads to process your WCF service input, and I/O threads to wait for asynchronous send/receive operation completion (which is supported on Windows OS level by [overlapped I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O) mechanism).

Keeping above in mind, let's have a look which threads are being utilized for both approaches by using [ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method:

```
 int worker;
 int ioCompletion;
 ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out worker, out ioCompletion);
 Console.WriteLine("{0} worker and {1} I/O threads are available", worker, ioCompletion);
```

I'll just show results of Thread Pool utilization for client side, but it's the same for server side as well.

**APM approach for one way WCF operation.**

For WCF contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {
     [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true)]
     IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething(int value, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

     void EndDoSomething(IAsyncResult result);
 }
```

Lets send 100 requests from client to server using next code:

```
ChannelFactory<IService1> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>();
var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int worker;
    int ioCompletion;
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out worker, out ioCompletion);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} worker and {1} I/O threads are available", worker, ioCompletion);

    client.BeginDoSomething(i, asyncCallback, null);
}
```

Output is:

```
1023 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 996 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 996 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 996 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
```

As you can see all worker threads are available on my x4 core machine and several I/O threads are being utilized.

**Running synchronous one way operation as TPL Task.**

For WCF contract:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService2
 {
     [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
     void DoSomething(int value);
 }
```

Let's run 100 requests from client to server using next code (just want to notice that TPL uses CLR ThreadPool underhood):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int worker;
    int ioCompletion;
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out worker, out ioCompletion);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} worker and {1} I/O threads are available", worker, ioCompletion);

    Task.Run(() => client.DoSomething(i));
}
```

Output is:

```
1023 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1022 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1021 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1020 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1019 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
```

As you can see, now worker threads are being utilized, but not I/O threads.

**So, what's the recommended approach?**

As summary, your solution should:

- Utilize worker and I/O threads from thread pool (especially, for highlyloaded applications) to prevent bottlenecks;
- Wrap asynchronous operation in Task, so you can get all benefits of TPL and new C# async/await features;
- It's absolutely reasonable to execute OneWay operation asynchronously
  (considering, sometimes [OneWay is not OneWay](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/gerben/archive/2010/02/01/wcf-best-practice-5-one-way-is-not-always-really-one-way.aspx) actually).

So, recommended approach is [Task-based asynchronous pattern for WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx), that satisfies all requirements above.

**Task-based asynchronous pattern for WCF.**

For contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService3
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task DoSomethingAsync(int value);
}
```

Lets send 100 requests again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     int worker;
     int ioCompletion;
     ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out worker, out ioCompletion);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} worker and {1} I/O threads are available", worker, ioCompletion);
     client.DoSomethingAsync(i);
}
```

Output:

```
1023 worker and 1000 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 998 I/O threads are available
1023 worker and 999 I/O threads are available
```

Answer (score 1):

**`OneWay = true`**

If you use the `OneWay` attribute, the client won't wait for the service to finish execution of the method. You can test that out easily by creating a service method which doesn't do anything but waits. A client will call the service method (even synchronously) and move on.

You can test that very easily by writing a simple test method in your service:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
```

and check the behaviour when you call it with and without the `OneWay` attribute. As such, it's somewhat pointless to call a `OneWay` method it asynchronously, although I suspect doing so means you're pushing very minor things (like creating the request and sending whatever data you send) to another thread, so it might still be useful.

**`AsyncPattern = true`**

This is useful if you want the client to wait for the operation to end (before it starts another for example). In case of `OneWay`, the client will send a request and forget about it - it doesn't care what's going on. With an `AsyncPattern` the client will wait for a notification when the service finishes executing the method.

The pattern also has one more added benefit - if you need it, it allows you to run some code when the method finishes execution on the service. It's useful when, for example, creating a `DuplexService`, which needs to manage client handlers and send notifications to clients when certain events occur.

PS. I'm a bit uncertain with regards to this part of your post: "*using shared contracts not generating from svcutil or add service reference*". I don't think it matters for my answer, but just in case, I'm leaving this disclaimer here. ;)