# In c#, how to check the thread from threadpool is a worker thread or an I/O thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, threadpool

Is it possible to recognize a thread is a worker or an I/O.

I know the code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread
```

this code is to show whether it is a thread pool thread, but it seems no method to show if it's a worker thread.

How can I check it? Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099947/simple-description-of-worker-and-i-o-threads-in-net - `There is really no technical difference between 'worker thread' and 'I/O thread'` in Dynamix AX there is something called `.isWorkerThread` but not sure If I am missing any context apart from that `:)`

Comment: I/O thread is a thread that executes I/O callbacks. So any asynchronous I/O callbacks will be processed on ThreadPool I/O threads. If you need to know on which thread you're running outside of the callback method itself, you might need a redesign :) At the very least, you could pass that information as a parameter if needed. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Luaan, thank you for your answer. I just test some code, to see which kind of thread handle the callback.

Comment: Well, do note that separating threadpool threads into worker and I/O is an implementation detail, mostly. It can change at any time, so you shouldn't really rely on the specifics - new pools can be added at any time, and the existing merged as well. Remember the patterns instead - in an asynchronous callback, you only want to do as little work as reasonable, if you need to do more than a bit, schedule the work further (either using `ThreadPool.QueueWorkerItem`, `Task.Run` or some other mechanism if you have your own scheduling for example).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the threads except for the pool they were/are in as you can read here: [Simple description of worker and I/O threads in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099947/simple-description-of-worker-and-i-o-threads-in-net?lq=1)

A thread has no knowledge about the pool that it came from. So this is not possible.